# How to programatically get a link to custom timer job settings?

Tags: 2010, 2013, development, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

I have created a custom timer job and deployed it to all web applications. In a custom central administration application page, I would like to show **links** to this timer job (e.g. 2 links if there are 2 web applications), i.e. to timer job settings to make it easier for the user to find the job. When user clicks the link, I'd like to open the same timer job settings/schedule page that opens when you navigate to it via  *Central Administration : Job Definitions*.

How can I construct URLs that will point to my custom timer jobs settings? Class implementing `SPFeatureReceiver` has GUID assigned to it, but I don't know how to use this to get a full link like:

```
http://srvr/_admin/JobEdit.aspx?JobId=ffccdd35-4444-4b22-b47b-73bf7039f777
```

Note that the GUID in the URL is not the same as the GUID provided in code, as each web app will have a different URL to the timer job settings. Can the URL somehow be obtained via `SPWebApplication`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every web application you can do the following:

1. Get your timer job definition (SPJobDefinition) from SPWebApplication.JobDefinitions
2. Get the guid:

   ```
   string jobDefID = SPJobDefinition.Id.ToString();
   ```
3. Add the guid in the query string

   ```
   http://srvr/_admin/JobEdit.aspx?JobId=jobDefID
   ```

Comment: Do you know how I can get the `http://srvr/_admin/JobEdit.aspx` URL programatically? I can use `Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local.Sites[0]` to get `http://srvr/`, but how about the other part - is it always fixed and can therefore I just hardcode it?

Comment: _admin/JobEdit.aspx is always the same. It is an application page in Admin folder in SharePoint Root folder.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

```
SPWebApplication webApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri(webAppUrl));

var customJob = (from job in webApp.JobDefinitions where job.Name == "MyTimerJobName" select job).Single(); // for some reason wont't work if I try to get the job using [name]

string jobUrl =  Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local.Sites[0].Url + "/_admin/JobEdit.aspx?JobId=" +  timerJob.Id.ToString();
```

Comment: Anyone knows why `var customJob = (from job in webApp.JobDefinitions where job.Name == "MyTimerJobName" select job).Single();` works and why `webapp.JobDefinitions["MyTimerJobName"]` under SP 2013 does NOT work?